# Does capillary rise violate hydrostatic paradox?

Tags: fluid-statics, capillary-action

If $p$ is a pressure and $p_A = p_{\text{atm}} + hdg,\,$ $p_B = p_{\text{atm}}$, is hydrostatic paradox violated, shouldn't $p_A=p_B$?

[image]

Comment: So P(A) need not be equal to P(B)???

Comment: You must have meant hydrostatic _principle_ rather than hydrostatic _paradox_. ;) A paradox cannot be "violated"--rather, it appears to violate principles. And true principles resolve the paradox rather than violating it. :P

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The pressures at A and B are indeed equal.  However, the pressure in the fluid immediately below the curved meniscus is equal to $p_{atm}-hdg$ as a result of surface tension.  So the pressure at A is $$p_A=p_{atm}-hdg+hdg=p_{atm}=p_B$$That is, there is a discontinuous change in pressure across the meniscus as a result of the surface tension in combination with the curvature.  The pressure on the upper side of the interface is $p_{atm}$ and the pressure on the lower side of the interface is $p_{atm}-hdg$.

Answer (score 5):

$p_A$ *is* equal to $p_B$ here. The disparity is arising due to the fact that [pressure just outside the meniscus is greater than the pressure inside](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_tension#Surface_curvature_and_pressure). This is due to the curvature of the meniscus and surface tension.
This difference is compensated by $hdg$ to make $p_A=p_B$.